Can cropped images that came from innocent photos be considered illegal?
A while back I came across a series of photos on social media all featuring a very young girl. She was in a bathing suit in some and a skirt/dress in the others. Those photos weren’t explicit; they looked like they came from a family member. I’m guessing the poster wasn’t the one who took the actual photos. The last two photos cropped the original photos and zoomed in to focus specifically on the poor girl’s private area. Obviously it was fully covered by clothing but still clearly cropped and zoomed to focus just on that area. The caption of the post was sexual/disgusting. I reported the post immediately but have recently been thinking back on it and did some research and am now a bit worried the photos, specifically the cropped ones, may have been illegal under US federal law. I’m now a bit paranoid seeing how I viewed content that could very well be illegal.

US federal law seems to be concerned mostly with images of exposed sexual body parts or depicting sexual activity.  State law may differ.  But reporting the post should protect you from criminal liability; if it didn't, nobody would ever report anything because doing so would lead to prosecution.

Why would you be in trouble? You didn't create the photos, you didn't save them on your computer (did you?), you didn't deliberately seek them out. How could you be liable for accidentally viewing something, no matter how explicit? This would mean that anyone who encounters child porn and tries to report it is also guilty.

To extend on @phoog's comment: It's not illegal to report something as a possible crime that turns out to be lawful as long the reporter (you) holds the honest belief that a criminal act is likely to have occurred. Generally speaking, you should be clear as long as you clarify that you're voicing a suspicion rather than an accusation and you're not trying to harm the suspect's reputation/creditworthiness (whether by intent or recklessness).

@Barmar Your incredulity is not warranted. There are plenty of things a more-or-less reasonable person might honestly do in this situation, that could be found criminal. For instance, taking a screenshot as "evidence" to report to the police, could well be criminal and people have been prosecuted - at least in the UK - for similar actions. Now of course in this case the OP is completely safe. But they are right to worry, and encouraging them to kind of vaguely argue about what must be the case for the law to be reasonable is dangerous.

@Barmar Your computer necessarily downloaded a copy of the picture in order for you to view it. It—or you—may or may not have deleted it afterwards, but it definitely was in the memory of the computer it was viewed on at least long enough for the viewing to happen.

@KRyan That's not usually how the law interprets these things. (Unless they want to pile on charges, of course.) See: copyright law.

@wizzwizz4 Oh sure, I’m just saying that it’s not necessarily cut-and-dry as suggested, and the fact that the law can at least sometimes choose to interpret things that way means it’s valid to ask if it might do so in this case.

Yes
australia
While this is a matter primarily of state law, the use of the internet engages Federal jurisdiction. In any event, the definition of illegal child pornography is similar: the sexualized depiction of a person who is or appears to be under the age of 16.
The types of images you describe could meet the definition, but it’s a case-by-case determination by the trier of fact. The decision is an objective one made on the content of the images themselves and not the methods or motivations of the maker. See Director of Public Prosecutions (NSW) v Annetts [2009] NSWCCA 86

10 In my opinion his Honour was correct to determine that the question which the definition in s 91H raises is objective and is to be answered by considering the content of the material about which complaint has been made. The fact that the images were secretly recorded is not relevant to whether or not the material is child pornography. Furthermore, the reasons which motivated the photographer are not relevant. These matters may inform an understanding of the context in which the film was made but are not relevant to an understanding of whether or not the video depicts boys in a “sexual context.” That question must be answered after considering the content of the film itself.
11 For that reason the content of the images contained in the video is relevant to the issue raised by the statute. The fact that all the images were of young boys and the camera has concentrated on their genitalia are both relevant to the question of whether or not the images depicted are of a person or persons in a “sexual context.” Of course it may be that after consideration of the content of a video, including a video containing a sequence of images of the genitalia of young boys, it could not be concluded that the video depicts boys in a sexual context. The images may have been made for a medical or artistic purpose and are depicted in that context. However, a conclusion that the images depict persons under 16 in “sexual context” may be informed by the number of images, the gestures of those photographed and the portion or portions of the body, including the genitalia, depicted.


What criteria would the trier of fact be instructed to use in making that determination?

@bdb484 Even cartoons are illegal in Australia. Someone got convicted because of porn of The Simpsons, IIRC. I think I remember reading that people have even been charged with possession of child porn because of pictures of adult women with A-cup breasts.

Of course, not a lawyer, not legal advice. Just stuff I've heard that I really don't want to Google

Yes
germany
The legal situation is very much like the one in Australia as described in Dale's answer. The German Criminal Code defines illegal pornographic depictions of children and youths as, among other,

the reproduction of a child in a state of full or partial undress in a provocatively sexual pose

section 184b(1)(1)(b)
and

the reproduction of a person over 14 years of age but under 18 years of age in a state of full or partial undress in a provocatively sexual pose

section 184c(1)(1)(b)
respectively.
The sexual provocativeness of a pose may depend on the context and the photographer and editor can alter the context through omission (among other means). Thus, it could be argued that a deliberate focus of the reproduction of area of the primary sexual organs of a minor in a bathing suit shows criminal intent to create and/or distribute pornographic material involving minors.

Are private parts that are covered by a bathing suit considered "full or partial undress". Also OP states the pictures could be "family photos", so I don't think "provocatively sexual pose" applies either. I get the editor argument, but is there precedent that cropping would be considered "sexual pose"?

Unfortunately I can't find any precedent in particular but I recall multiple occasions in which collections of family bathroom, beach, sauna, and other nudist pictures of minors who wouldn't be considered provocative on their own were classified as provocative within the context of those collections whose collectors were clearly distributing them for the purpose of sexual arousal.
